# Workplace is stalling on offer letter

Tags: new-job

I'm currently working as an "IT Executive" for a small private school in singapore.

I'm currently in a somewhat unusual arrangement with an employer - I interviewed at with them, with a recommendation from a friend of their director. When I asked about timings, I was told "come before 8" and "Its 44 hours a week".

So far, outside of an NDA, nothing's been signed. I've not really been given a clear idea of my timings (I just do 8-6.30 for now). HR's one person and giving me the runaround when I asked over the past 2 working days.

Otherwise, I seem to be working as per normal, outside the complete lack of onboarding. This feels *odd*. I've gotten a verbal agreement on a 3 month probation, but I've never been in a situation where I've started work without any formal agreement.

Outside of hounding HR. and my current, acting superior, what's the right way to deal with this?

Comment: Have you *asked* the HR for the offer letter? It is not clear from the question if you have done that. What did they say?

Comment: Yeah, I've asked HR. HR says they're waiting on the CEO to confirm my job title

Comment: Are you getting paid?

Comment: In theory, yes - at the end of the month, as is customary here.

Comment: Just to check, have you already *started* work without any offer letter or any contract, or are you looking to start?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**A verbal offer is worth nothing.**

Insist for a written offer, otherwise you could be told the wonderful sentence "I can't pay you this month since you're not an official employee" or something else. And since you didn't sign anything, you can't tell them they're wrong.

If no offer has been done after you tried to reach HR multiple times, you should tell them you can't work as long as no contract has been made since you have no job security.

Settle them for a contract and a real starting date, because your current situation seems like a big red flag waiting to happen.

Comment: "A verbal offer is not worth the paper it's written on."

Comment: Or he could email the HR guy reiterating his request, confirming the salary he agreed to, plus any terms that are important to him, and stating the fact that he has already started working for them. This way, he would be leaving a paper trail at least, assuming the HR guy acknowledges the receipt of that message without raising any objection.

Comment: I kinda asked them how long my notice period would be, that this was mildly frustrating, and how long my notice period was... which did wonders. There's a few odd things (like a post dated contract and starting date) but more or less... things worked out for now. Its left me with a slightly negative view of how my workplace is run, but I'll get over it.